# copy-and-swap idiom, with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, idioms

I read [interesting things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) about the copy-and-swap idiom. My question is concerning the implementation of the `swap` method when inheriting from another class.

```
class Foo : public Bar
{
    int _m1;
    string _m2;
    .../...
public:
    void swap(Foo &a, Foo &b)
    {
         using std::swap;

         swap(a._m1, b._m1);
         swap(a._m2, b._m2);
         // what about the Bar private members ???
    }
    .../...
};
```

Comment: No comments on the private base-class members??  Usually a custom copy operator is implemented because there is additional handling of special cases, e.g. pointers.  Such additional, crucial logic should exist outside the swap function(s), and it can also include private members.  The answers only show how to handle the swap but leaves the "copy" part of the idiom unanswered.  Anyone have a good pattern for the implementing the entire idiom with inheritance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would swap the subobjects:

```
swap(static_cast<Bar&>(a), static_cast<Bar&>(b));
```

You may need to implement the swap function for `Bar`, if `std::swap` doesn't do the job. Also note that `swap` should be a non-member (and a friend if necessary).

Comment: To avoid casting, you can do "Bar &a_bar = a, &b_bar = b; swap(a_bar,b_bar);"

Answer (score 2):

Just cast it up to the base and let the compiler work it out:

`swap(static_cast<Bar&>(a), static_cast<Bar&)(b));`

Answer (score 0):

You would typically be doing it like this:

```
class Foo : public Bar
{
    int _m1;
    string _m2;
    .../...
public:
    void swap(Foo &b)
    {
         using std::swap;

         swap(_m1, b._m1);
         swap(_m2, b._m2);
         Bar::swap(b);
    }
    .../...
};
```

Comment: Except in the case where `Bar` doesn't implement a `Bar::swap(Bar &b)`. And see the link I posted about the inner/external method.

Comment: Ok, your method was not declared static or friend, so it confused me, but I didn't read the link so that is my fault.